# how to get the value from drop down and send it to the view.py method

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <label class="label-filter" style="margin-right: 12px; margin-top: 22px; font-size: 16px;" id="filter">Filter By Year</label>
      
        <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding: 3px; font-size: 12px; width: 100px; text-align: left; overflow: hidden;" id="year-button">Select Year</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="year-menu" name="selectedYear">
          <!-- Dynamic years will be generated here -->
        </ul>
      </div>
```

this is the code of the dropdown. I want that the selected one should be sent to the views. so I wrote this script code.

```
// Get the current year
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

// Set the maximum number of years to display in the dropdown menu
const maxYears = 50;

// Get the year menu element
const yearMenu = document.getElementById("year-menu");

// Set the height of the year menu and add a scrollbar
yearMenu.style.maxHeight = "200px";
yearMenu.style.overflowY = "scroll";

// Generate the years dynamically from 1950 to the current year, up to the maximum number of years
for (let year = currentYear; year >= 1950 && year > currentYear - maxYears; year--) {
  // Create a new year item
  const yearItem = document.createElement("li");

  // Create a new year link
  const yearLink = document.createElement("a");
  yearLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
  yearLink.textContent = year;

  // Add an event listener to update the year button when a year is clicked
  yearLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("year-button").textContent = year;
  });

  // Add the year link to the year item
  yearItem.appendChild(yearLink);

  // Add the year item to the year menu
  yearMenu.appendChild(yearItem);
}
```

but if I submit the form. It is throwing the error and if in the model I am making the field `null=True` and then try, it will then still not send any data to the views. how do I fix this?

if I submit the form. It is throwing the error and if in the model I am making the field null= True and then try, it will then still not send any data to the views. how do I fix this?